# open login activity when I press back button but i want to stop app android

Tags: android, android-activity, asynchronous

i have create a login activity when I logged in want to store login then i opened Main activity but when I press back button then i came to login activity.

i want to stop app and when i press back button on Main activity.

Again i opened my app, see login activity.

I want to store login details in local and when i open app check credentials from local and open Main activity not login activity.

please help me with description what you did ?

My code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       String str = result.trim();
        if(str.equals("success")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class));
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Either Username or Password is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to show the login activity again when pressed back button used finish() method on the login activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   String str = result.trim();
    if(str.equals("success")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class));
    finish();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Either Username or Password is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

and to kill the app on pressing back button use this

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Login.this.finish;
}
```

and its better to use sharedpreference to store if the user is logged in or not instead of a String.

Hope it was helpful.